# Why does reassigning a smart pointer to itself cause destruction?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

## TLDR

Why does the line `t_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Test>(t_ptr.get());` cause the destructor to be called?

The line seems to just innocently assign `t_ptr` back to itself...

Further, why am I able to continue calling methods after the supposed destruction?

### Example Code

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test()
        {
            printf("Constructor called: %p\n", this);
            i = 0;
        };
        void print()
        {
            printf("%d\n", i++);
        };
        ~Test()
        {
            printf("Destructor called: %p\n", this);
        };
    private:
        int i;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Test> t_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Test>(new Test());
    t_ptr->print();
    t_ptr->print();
    t_ptr->print();
    t_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Test>(t_ptr.get());
    t_ptr->print();
    t_ptr->print();
    t_ptr->print();
};
```

The output is

```
Constructor called: 0x55c9811a1e70
0
1
2
Destructor called: 0x55c9811a1e70
0
1
2
Destructor called: 0x55c9811a1e70
```

Comment: Isn't this (destruction) just expected behaviour upon reassigning a unique_ptr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does the line `t_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Test>(t_ptr.get());` cause the destructor to be called?

Because `unique_ptr` needs to delete the currently held object when assigning it a new one. Otherwise it would leak the current object. However, it will not check whether the new one is actually the same as the current one. If you do that, the behavior is undefined.

> Further, why am I able to continue calling methods after the supposed destruction?

Because this is undefined behavior. You are calling functions on an object that has been deleted. What happens when you do that is undefined. On your system it works, on mine it crashes.

### (Off-topic side note)

I recommend getting into the habit of never using `new` if you can avoid it, and using `std::make_unique` (or `std::make_shared` for `shared_ptr`) instead:

```
auto t_ptr = std::make_unique<Test>();
```

There's benefits with exception safety in some cases when the constructor throws. Basically, as of 2019 at least, the current rule of thumb is "do not use `new` or `delete`."