# Reassign a smart pointer in a function without passing ownership?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

## Background

With normal pointers, I can do something like the following

```
void conditional_reassign(MyClass* ptr)
{
    if (my_condition)
    {
        delete ptr;
        ptr = new MyClass(new_param);
    }
}
```

And I can pass in the pointer I want to change like following

```
MyClass* ptr = new MyClass(old_param);
conditional_reassign(ptr);
```

I wish to reimplement this with `std::unique_ptr`.  Here's what I came up with

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> conditional_reassign2(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr)
{
    if (my_condition)
    {
        ptr = std::make_unique<MyClass>(new_param);
    }
    return std::move(ptr);
}
```

And I would call it with the following

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr = make_unique<MyClass>(old_param);
ptr = std::move(conditional_reassign2(std::move(ptr)));
```

## Question

I'm not quite happy with the verbosity of the line

```
ptr = conditional_reassign2(std::move(ptr));
```

Is there a way to implement `conditional_reassign2` so that I can call it in a manner similar to `conditional_reassign(ptr)`

## Edit

I should note a major issue with

```
ptr = std::move(conditional_reassign2(std::move(ptr)));
```

is that it will destroy the original object `ptr` pointed to regardless of `my_condition` (see [Why does reassigning a smart pointer to itself cause destruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627418/why-does-reassigning-a-smart-pointer-to-itself-cause-destruction/55627514#55627514))

Comment: Apologies if I'm misreading your question, but `conditional_reassign` doesn't do what you appear to think it does.  It does not change the caller's `ptr`.  For that, you'd need to pass it by reference or make the function take a pointer to pointer.

Comment: The outer std::move is redundant.

Comment: Why do you use same ptr for return value and as a parameter?

Comment: Your `conditional_reassign()` function (as pointed out) results in undefined behavior, and is a prime example of why you should convert your code to use `unique_ptr`. Your current bug is way more difficult to implement with `unique_ptr` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you need to pass the pointer by reference

```
void conditional_reassign2(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>& ptr) {...}

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myPtr;
conditional_reassign2(myPtr);
```

or return the pointer, which requires a single move

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> conditional_reassign2(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr) {...}

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myPtr;
myPtr = conditional_reassign2(std::move(myPtr));
```

Also you can return ptr directly from the function without explicitly calling move.

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> conditional_reassign2(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr)
{
    if (my_condition)
        ptr = std::make_unique<MyClass>(new_param);
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `conditional_reassign2()` function to take the `std::unique_ptr` *by reference* instead of *by value*:

```
void conditional_reassign2(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>& ptr)
{
    if (my_condition)
    {
        ptr = std::make_unique<MyClass>(new_param);
    }
}
```

This way the function can directly modify the instance that is being passed, no need to transfer the ownership.

Assuming that `ptr` is an `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>`, then calling `conditional_reassign2()` would be in this case:

```
conditional_reassign2(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example does not do what you intend it to do. As `ptr` is passed by value, the caller's pointer will not be modified. So if `my_condition` is `true`, the caller has a pointer that points to a deleted object, and the address to which the newly created object is stored at is lost after the function returns.

Here is your first example fixed (the argument is now a reference to a pointer):

```
void conditional_reassign((MyClass*)& ptr)
{
    if (my_condition)
    {
        delete ptr;
        ptr = new MyClass(new_param);
    }
}
```

To use unique_ptr, you can also use references and not return anything. This way no need to deal with `std::move`

```
void conditional_reassign2(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>& ptr)
{
    if (my_condition)
    {
        ptr =  std::make_unique<MyClass>(new_param);
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr = make_unique<MyClass>(old_param);
conditional_reassign2(ptr);
```

Or you can use return/move semantics:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> conditional_reassign(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr)
{
    if (my_condition)
    {
        return std::make_unique<MyClass>(new_param);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr = make_unique<MyClass>(old_param);
ptr = conditional_reassign2(std::move(ptr));
```